# Add preventDefault to the any list elements of an unordered list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I need to add prevent default to a list element of an unordered list

```
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-2">
<li class="select2-results- 
dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2- 
result-label" id="select2-result-label-4" role="option"><div class="flex justify-space- 
between align-center py1 px2">
  <div>
    <p class="m0">MY REView</p>
    <p class="grey-20 m0">Active</p>
  </div>

  <div class="cycle-switcher-result-label invisible hide">Actions Required</div>
  </div></div>
  </li>
  <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result- 
  selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label- 
  5" role="option"><div class="flex justify-space-between align-center py1 px2">
  <div>
    <p class="m0">TEST MY REVIEW</p>
    <p class="grey-20 m0">Active</p>
  </div>

 <div class="cycle-switcher-result-label invisible hide">Actions Required</div>
 </div></div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

I tried to add on the  element itself, it doesn't work

```
let item = document.getElementsByClassName('select2-results')[0]
$(item).on('mousedown',function(e){console.log("showCycleSwitcher mouse down..."); 
e.preventDefault();})
```

How do I ensure the mousedown preventDefault applies to the click li element

Comment: What is their default behavior, that you're trying to prevent? o_O P.s. You can use `$('.select2-results').eq(0).on... ` selector, to catch only first element.

Comment: If you are using backbone why are you even binding events like this? Please create [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

As far as I see you are mixing jQuery with vanila js.

```
let item = document.getElementsByClassName('select2-results')[0];
item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("showCycleSwitcher mouse down...");
});
```

This is working for me and does not require jQuery.

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/fbwyk3cj/1/

Comment: I tried it also before posting and it's logging to my console on click. What is not working for you?

Comment: Come on there is a link to the fiddle that works. Did you tried it?